# Count Unique Days Groupby Month/Year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Good Morning,

I am working on a problem I hope has a very simple solution but I can't seem to get it formatted in the most useful format.

In my analysis work, we are looking at adding a full time shift to a remote location and to see if this would be productive or keep with Per Diem work, we need to analyze for proposed shifts (Hours and Days of the week) how many dispatches they could have, and more importantly, how many days with historical data would have had zero dispatches.

My main data is just dispatch date which is formatted as with thousands of rows

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

To make it more easy to work with, I started my code as:

```
import pandas as pd

shift_df = pd.read_excel('dfname.xlsx')
shift_df['Year'] = shift_df['Dispatch'].dt.year
shift_df['Month'] = shift_df['Dispatch'].dt.month
shift_df['WeekDay'] = shift_df['Dispatch'].dt.weekday
```

I then try and do a group by with a desired output of:

```
Year   | Month  | Unique Days
2017       1        13
2017       2        16
2017       3        19
```

with the formula:

```
shift_df[disp_time].groupby([(shift_df[disp_time].dt.year),(shift_df[disp_time].dt.month)]).count()
```

It produces close to what I want in the form of:

```
Year |  Month  | TOTAL RECORDS
2017     1         29
```

The problem is, we often have multiple dispatches on one day so that counted all records on that day.  I tried doing some level of .agg("total":pd.Seriesl.nunique()) but that gave me unique month numbers.  I can produce it and hand count the total days represetned in each month with a simple groupby adding [shift_df['Day'] but that produces more work then I'd hope for.

Am I using the right feature, or should I try and use a pivot function?

Thank you for all your help,

Andy M.

------------EDITED For Clarification---------------

To add a brief edit per request my warehouse as many fields but I filter down my DF and do some data cleaning to include some basic items as this is a pure summary count while we examine shift possibilities and what historically it would have looked like.

My DF I am working with I have narrowed down just dispatch date - then I break down my dispatch date as soon in my example code:

----shift_DF----

```
Dispatch Date / Time    | Dispatch Year    | Dispatch Month   | Dispatch Day
 1/1/2017 05:32:53          2017                  1                  1
 1/7/2017 15:32:53          2017                  1                  7
 1/1/2017 05:32:53          2017                  1                  1
 1/3/2017 03:32:53          2017                  1                  3
 1/1/2017 05:32:53          2017                  1                  1
```

My desired ouput from this would look like

```
dispatch year | dispatch month | unique days
2017             1                  3
```

Problem is my output now looks like

```
dispatch year | dispatch month | unique days
2017             1                  5
```

It counts all 5 records that match the month, when in reality we had 3 dispatches on the 1st of Jan and I only want to count Jan 1 once.

This data is replicated over many years/months/days but the goal is to summarize in the hierarchy of years - months - unique days every time.

Comment: Can you provide some dummy data and expected output? So it's obvious what it is you're doing. Ty

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ added some updated information on exactly what I am looking for, how it is currently set up and my exact error.  I hope this was enough to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have a column called `Date`:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce')
s

0   2017-01-01 05:32:53
1   2017-01-07 15:32:53
2   2017-01-01 05:32:53
3   2017-01-03 03:32:53
4   2017-01-01 05:32:53
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You really don't need any extra columns. Just use `groupby` + `nunique`:

```
(s.groupby([s.dt.year, s.dt.month])
  .nunique()
  .rename_axis(['year', 'month'])
  .reset_index(name='unique days'))

   year  month  unique days
0  2017      1            3
```

Comment: Nice.. I was just about to do the same thing as you, but then I got a phone call. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston Sorry about that! Thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Wow, I was over complicating my thinking, so simple.  Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
count = df.groupby([(df.index.year),(df.index.month)]).count()
```

set date as the index and run above thing

Comment: since sample data was provided it would be desirable for you to show an output to corroborate your code